# How to make it permanently day/night

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I make it always day/night?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can disable the day/night cycle completely using a gamerule:

```
/gamerule doDaylightCycle false
```

Once you have done that, you can set the time to whatever time you want using

```
/time set <time>
```

where `<time>` is any number between 0 and 23999. 0 is 6 a.m. 1000 is 7 a.m., 2000 is 8 a.m. and so on (the wiki has a [list](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Day-night_cycle#Conversions)). Unless you change the time manually, it will stay fixed at that particular time, [even when you sleep in a bed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed#Trivia):

> If you sleep when the `/gamerule doDaylightCycle` is turned off, you will fall asleep, but wake up at night.